# Kubernetes ImagePullBackOff caused by no space left on device

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this weird error on my Kubernetes test cluster. I'm running Kubernetes 1.7.0 and docker `Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802`

I have a separate volume mounted as `/dockerdata` and symlinked `/var/lib/docker` into this volume. I have ample space available on both my system volume and the dockerdata volume (more than 50% free). I still get ImagePullBackOff errors from kubernetes, the detailed error is:

`Failed to pull image "<redacted>": rpc error: code = 2 desc = failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: open /usr/share/man/es/man1/fakeroot-sysv.1.gz: no space left on device.`

If I manually clean up by removing stale images I can get around this, but as far as I can see I shouldn't have to - since none of my volumes are nearing full capacity (which I guess is also why the Kubernetes GC doesn't kick in).

I'm guessing there's something I don't understand about how Docker works in relation to local disks but I'm stumped. Any pointers appreciated.

Here's some more info:
symlink info:

`file /var/lib/docker
/var/lib/docker: symbolic link to /dockerdata`

`df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             2014736        0   2014736   0% /dev
tmpfs             404520    44628    359892  12% /run
/dev/xvda1      20263528  4121240  16125904  21% /
tmpfs            2022600        0   2022600   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2022600        0   2022600   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb       51475068 18385324  30451920  38% /dockerdata
tmpfs             404520        0    404520   0% /run/user/1000`

`lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial`

Comment: Inodes perhaps? df -ih

Comment: very likely. Seems that Inodes has issues with the overlay storage driver on docker. Overlay2 seems to be supported on Kubernetes 1.8, so I guess we'll upgrade, switch drivers, and hope this goes away.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this: 
`ls -lah ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`

Also then try to delete this file and will not affect any of your containers.

Comment: Thanks! We haven't had this problem after switching to Overlay2 and Docker 17.03.